# Calculating last order date by UserID from GA data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to calculate the last order date of an individual, by their UserID - my UserID is derived from a custom dimension from the automatically imported Google Analytics data.

I'm not sure how to go about this, i'm quite new to SQL, I think I might be looking for a window function, but not entirely sure!

Here is my code so far, but this returns the most recent order data against ALL IDs:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT MAX(date) AS lastorddate, customDimension.value AS UserID
FROM `PROJECTNAME.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
WHERE customDimension.index = 2
AND totals.transactions > 0
GROUP BY Date, UserID)
GROUP BY UserID, lastorddate
ORDER BY lastorddate DESC
LIMIT 500
```

Comment: Try MIN(date) then

Comment: Sorry, my question was wrong, I am looking to calculate the LAST order date, not first.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT MAX(date) AS lastorddate, customDimension.value AS UserID
FROM `PROJECTNAME.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
WHERE customDimension.index = 2
AND totals.transactions > 0
GROUP BY UserID
ORDER BY lastorddate DESC
LIMIT 500
```